# Making a rhombus shape using background images

Tags: css

I'm using the following test code to try create a rhombus type shape.  The span is a standard oblong, and the 2 sides will make it appear as a rhombus

```
**********
 *      * 
  ******
```

However, the before and after selectors don't seem to render anything.  I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong or if I'd just be better off positioning them absolutely.

Any ideas?

```
<style>

span {
width:50px;
height:20px;
color:white;
background-color:red;
padding:10px;
}

span:before {
background: url('left_side.png') left center no-repeat; 
height:43px; width:22px; 
}

span:after {
background: url('right_side.png') right center no-repeat; 
height:43px; width:22px;
}

</style>

<html>
<body>

<span>
Some text goes here
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    #demo { border-top: 100px solid red;
            border-left: 50px solid transparent;
            border-right: 50px solid transparent;
            height: 0; width: 100px; }
```

do it without images why people made css3

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sahilpopli/dRyLg/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
span:before  {
   content: url('left_side.png'); 
   height:43px; width:22px; 
}

span:after {
   content: url('right_side.png'); 
   height:43px; width:22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content` property is mandatory, even if left empty :

```
span:before {
    content : "";
    display:inline-block;
    background: url('left_side.png') left center no-repeat; 
    height:43px; width:22px; 
}

span:after {
    content : "";
    display:inline-block;
    background: url('right_side.png') right center no-repeat; 
    height:43px; width:22px;
}
```

**Edit :** added `display:inline-block;` for dimension properties to actually work with span, see this example http://jsfiddle.net/3nvhb/